# Iterating over running processes works fine just once

Tags: c#, winapi

I would like to retrieve information about all running processes that match a certain name pattern. I do that by using the following code I found online, which apparently is supposed to help with some privilige issues on Windows Vista and above. Sadly, that does not work for me. I am executing the following code as administrator.

The **Natives.OpenProcess** works fine the first time it is being called, but fails for every after call that by returning **IntPtr.Zero** and GetLastWin32Error() returns **"Access Denied"**.

```
public static string GetExecutablePathAboveVista(int ProcessId)
    {
        var buffer = new StringBuilder(1024);
        IntPtr hprocess = Natives.OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, false, ProcessId);

        if (hprocess != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            try
            {
                int size = buffer.Capacity;
                if (Natives.QueryFullProcessImageName(hprocess, 0, buffer, out size))
                {
                    return buffer.ToString();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Natives.CloseHandle(hprocess);
            }
        }
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, ..)` give you `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` when and only when you have no `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` enabled. so can be only 2 case: or before first call `GetExecutablePathAboveVista` you have enabled `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` in thread (if it have token) or process token. and before second/next calls you direct or faster of all indirect disable this privilege or impersonate thread with another token. or possible you say confuse processes - first time you open one process (id) and second time you try open another process (id) - not clear from your code.

> I am executing the following code as administrator.

this is not enough. this mean only that in your process token exist `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE`. (*with default windows settings, however this can be changed*) but you need that this privilege will be **enabled** in token, not just exist.

also

> that match a certain name pattern

if you need only process **name** without full path - you already have it when you enumerate all running processes.

also exist undocumented *SystemProcessIdInformation* information class for *ZwQuerySystemInformation* - with it you can got full path of process without open it and have any privileges.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your entire comment, but I think I get it. It still doesn't explain why the first call works and only the second call fails. If I have the privilege the first time, I should have it the second time since I'm not switching threads or anything fancy.

Comment: @a20eac1d - are you both time try open the same process id ? the *best* use `ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessIdInformation,..)` for get full path of executable. if you not want use undocumented api - you must **enable** `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` in your token before call `GetExecutablePathAboveVista`. may be some code between first and second calls disable this privilege in your token.